# locate the specific php file under classname

Tags: php

how do I locate the php file which was located inside the class name? I wanted to find the "wp-list-table widefat fixed striped posts" classname. I can easily locate the css folder php file, but if I try to locate the specific classname, how would I know in which folder?

Now Im using the notepad++ and using the find files, to locate the specific classname, but sometimes it takes me too much long due to many folders

Is there a program that could easily locate the folder location of the php file under that class name?

Thankyou

Comment: Wordpress generates these classes, I'm not sure there is a particular file that contains all of them at once

Comment: you should take each class individually and search in files and you'll have more luck searching for classes or ids of parent elements